memory leak in websocket++ broadcast server
I am making a websocket++ broadcast server which handles subscription and unsubscription by clients to certain tokens
upon subscribed the client receives continuous updates at an interval of 500ms which I send by reading a shared memory
in the shared memory my server acts as a reader, reading the shared memory and sending the updates to clients
the memory occupied by this server increases and when I reach approx 100 clients with 50 tokens each it ends up occupying around 5gb memory why is this happening
this is the main loop in my code which I believe causes error it is mostly identical to the one given on the websocket++ github repo
void read_shm_and_send_messages() {
    // while(true){
    int shmid = shmget(1234, 0, 0666);
    cout << shmid << endl;
    if (shmid == -1) {
        perror("shmget");
        exit(1);`your text`
    }

    // Attach the shared memory segment
    char *shmaddr = (char *)shmat(shmid, NULL, 0);
    if (shmaddr == (char *)-1) {
        perror("shmat");
        exit(1);
    }
    
    struct shmid_ds shmid_ds;
    shmctl(shmid, IPC_STAT, &shmid_ds);
    int num_integers = shmid_ds.shm_segsz / sizeof(trade_data); 

    // Allocate the values array dynamically based on the size of shared memory
    trade_data *values = new trade_data[num_integers];
    std::ofstream file("diff_values2.csv", std::ios::trunc);

    // Check if the file is opened successfully
    if (!file.is_open()) {
        std::cerr << "Error opening file." << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    // Write the header to the CSV file
    file << "time taken\n";
    while(true){
        // values = new trade_data[num_integers];
        // if(subscription_list.size() == 0){
        //     clear_shared_memory(shmid);
        // }

        // Read the stored integer values from the shared memory buffer
        // int values[150000];
        // memset(values, 0, num_integers * sizeof(trade_data));
        for (int i = 0; i < num_integers; ++i) {
            memcpy(&values[i], shmaddr + i * sizeof(trade_data), sizeof(trade_data));
        }

        auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        int count = 0;
        for(auto it:subscription_list){
            int token = it;
            count += mp[it].size();
            send_message_to_connections(token , values[token_index_map[token]]);
        }  

        auto end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        auto diff = end - start;
        if(!subscription_list.empty()) {
            // cout << "Time taken to publish message to all connections : " <<    std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli>(diff).count() << " ms"<< endl;

            file << std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli>(diff).count() << ", " << count << "\n";
            file.flush();

        }  
        // if(count == 5000){
        //     system("pkill client_test");
        // } 
        // sleep(2);
        // if(subscription_list.size() == 0){
        //     if (shmdt(shmaddr) == -1) {
        //         perror("shmdt");
        //         exit(1);
        //     }
        //     break;
        // }

        // if(count == 500) delete[] values;

        usleep(500);
        // sleep(2);

    }
    // delete[] values;

    // Detach the shared memory segment
    if (shmdt(shmaddr) == -1) {
        perror("shmdt");
        exit(1);
    }

}

I expected there to be a constant memory access and not increasing until my program crashed
